# Exact Scaling Dimension of the Energy Momentum Tensor in a Curved Background for 2D CFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In the derivation of the Weyl anomaly, in all derivations I could find, it is assumed that (trace of) energy momentum tensor has dimension 2 even in curved background. I believe it is meant that:
$$ \left<T(x) O(y)\right>_{g}= \lambda^{2+\Delta_O}\left<T(x) O(y)\right>_{\lambda^2 g}$$
and similar identities for other correlation functions. I see how to obtain this in flat space but I dont see how to obtain this in curved space.

Edit: I want to understand the claim that $\left<T(x)\right>$ must be proportional to $R$, ricci curvature, and $R^2$ etc. can't appear by dimensional analysis. I am not sure what is exactly meant by dimensional analysis here, my guess is the equation I wrote above.